# OCaml bindings for Z3: support for String sorts

Tags: ocaml, z3

I am trying to express the following function declaration using the OCaml API for Z3:

```
(declare-fun ctrl_p ((Int)) String)
```

However, I cannot find in the [documentation](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/index_values.html) an appropriate `mk_sort` function. Are there any suggested workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already need this functionality? The string functionality is brand new and was just made available for the other APIs. For OCaml we are also dealing with fixing GC interaction. You are of course welcome to provide a pull request.

Comment: Indeed, the OCaml API is currently undergoing restoration, but once that is done it's easy to add the strings, so bear with us for now.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. Out of curiosity: in which files should I look to add support for strings besides `src/api/ml/z3.ml` and `src/api/ml/z3.mli`? I see `scripts/update_api.py` is used to generate the C stubs but I am not entirely clear how that works.